# How to change text color for ListBox element using Triggers?

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms, xaml, wpf-controls

I have a ListBox (SurfaceListBox) and I need to change the text color for an element when the element has false on a specific property.

Looking at my code this works fine:

```
<DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsSelectable}" Value="False">
```

but setting the color using:

```
<Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Black"/>
```

does not work, and color is not changed.

Any idea how to solve it, or an alternative approch?

```
<Style x:Key="CategorySurfaceListBoxItemStyle"
        TargetType="{x:Type Custom:SurfaceListBoxItem}"
        BasedOn="{StaticResource ControlBaseStyle}">

    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Custom:SurfaceListBoxItem}">
                <Grid
                    x:Name="Grid"
                    Background="{StaticResource ControlHitAreaBrush}"
                    SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}">
                    <ContentPresenter x:Name="Content" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
    <!-- Disable dot items -->
    <Style.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsSelectable}" Value="False">
            <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="False"/>
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Black"/> <!--PROBLEM HERE-->
        </DataTrigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

Comment: Are you setting Foreground property somewhere else too?

Comment: Foreground property displays in the question now after formatting fixes.

Comment: Yes I have another style. Basically every item has a color and I need to override only some elements which has a specif propery

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve the problem in this way:

- Remove any style which will set the foreground color (this avoid overriding of color).
- Using
  the following code:

  ```
      <Style.Triggers>
          <!-- Disable dot items and style -->
          <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsSelectable}" Value="False">
              <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="False"/>
              <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Black"/>
          </DataTrigger>
          <!-- Enable other elements and style -->
          <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsSelectable}" Value="True">
              <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="True"/>
              <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#1799c3"/>
          </DataTrigger>
      </Style.Triggers>
  ```

Comment: Yes - you forget the 'True` condtion for `Trigger` - your `Trigger` was working only on `False` condition. And what was heppend when it was `True`. You should add thic case.

Comment: Thanks Jasper for your comment, case for the true condition is present for my understanding, please have a look. Thanks.